# What's the correct endpoint to access github repositories on github API?

Tags: javascript, api, github

I'm doing a request to github's API to get the following items: the repo's name, the repo owner's name, the repo url, the repo description, the number of stars, the license type, and if the repo is forked or not. I have this endpoint according to github's API docs:[https://api.github.com/search/repositories?q={query}{&page,per_page,sort,order}](https://api.github.com/search/repositories?q=%7Bquery%7D%7B&page,per_page,sort,order%7D)

But that doesn't seem to work. Did I forget something? the github API is here: https://help.github.com/articles/searching-repositories. Also here is the request I'm making:

```
     getRepos = (repoinfo) => {
        return fetch(`https://api.github.com/search/repositories?q={query} {&page,per_page,sort,order}`)
        .then(respone => Response.json())
        .then(response => {
          return response
        })
     }
```

Comment: Can you share your command/code so we can help you?

Comment: @rakwaht I just added it in

Comment: You are supposed to replace {query} and the rest with parameters. See my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Works for me. Here I search for the repos containing Labyrinth in the readme:

https://api.github.com/search/repositories?q=labyrinth+in:readme&type=repository

Or, if you want a specfific repo, use https://api.github.com/repos/:owner/:repo like this:

https://api.github.com/repos/draluy/labyrinth

Comment: Hi David and thanks. I kind of want it to be dynamic so that it takes a name from a search input from a form.

Comment: You could just concatenate https://api.github.com/search/repositories?q= with the search term